# TicTacToe game, no output

Tags: java

In this code I want to create a 3x3 board game, but nothing appears on the screen..(code compiles correctly but doesn't show output)
I think the problem is in the `main` method... Can't figure it out... Please help!

```
package games;

import games.board.*;

public class BoardGameTester {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private static Board gb;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gb = new Board(3, 3);
}

 }
```

Here is a board.java:

```
package games.board;
   public class Board  {
private Cell[][] cells;
public Board(int rows, int columns) {
cells = new Cell[rows][columns];
for( int r = 0; r < cells[0].length; r++ ) {
for (int c = 0; c < cells[1].length; c++) {
cells[r][c] = new Cell(r,c);
}
}
}
public void setCell(Mark mark, int row, int column) throws
IllegalArgumentException {
if (cells[row][column].getContent() == Mark.EMPTY)
cells[row][column].setContent(mark);
else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Player already there!");
}
public Cell getCell(int row, int column) {
return cells[row][column];
}
public String toString() {
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for( int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++ ) {
str.append("|"); 


for (int c = 0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {
switch(cells[r][c].getContent()) {
case NOUGHT:
    str.append("O");
    break;
    case CROSS:
    str.append("X");
    break;
    case YELLOW:
    str.append("Y");
    break;
    case RED:
    str.append("R");
    break;
    case BLUE:
    str.append("B");
    break;
    case GREEN:
    str.append("G");
    break;
    case MAGENTA:
    str.append("M");
    break;
    case ORANGE:
    str.append("M");
    break;
    default: //Empty
    str.append("");
    }
    str.append("|");
    }
    str.append("\n");
    }
    return str.toString();

}
}
```

Here is a cell.java

```
package games.board;

public class Cell {
private Mark content;
private int row, column;
public Cell(int row, int column) {
this.row = row;
this.column = column;
content = Mark.EMPTY;
}
public Mark getContent() { return content; }
public void setContent(Mark content) { this.content = content; }
public int getRow() { return row; }
public int getColumn() { return column; }
}
```

Here is mark.java

```
package games.board;

public enum Mark {

EMPTY, NOUGHT, CROSS, YELLOW, RED, BLUE, GREEN, MAGENTA, ORANGE
}
```

Here is outcome.java

```
package games.board;

public enum Outcome {
PLAYER1_WIN, PLAYER2_WIN, CONTINUE, TIE
}
```

here is player.java

```
package games.board;

public enum Player {
FIRST,SECOND
}
```

Comment: Please format your source code - it's very hard to read with no indentation. You should also tell us what diagnostic steps you've performed so far. Have you run this in the debugger?

Comment: please post the console output while compiling and running, Does the program exits?

Comment: there is no output in your code...

Comment: Exactly what output are you expecting?  I see 0 calls to println or any other output function.

Comment: program do not show any output...problem is in main method i think in board(3,3).It's logical error...

Comment: This isn't YOUR code.

Comment: You should add some `println`'s or atleast something that would output something. If you don't have calls to these, then don't expect output! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gb = new Board(3, 3);
    System.out.println(gb.toString());
}
```

Comment: @kevinsa5 Yep, thanks for pointing out ;) I wrote the answer too fast.

Answer (score 0):

you are not genereting any output
to print the board to the console try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gb = new Board(3, 3);
    System.out.println(gb);
}
```

it will invoke the `gb.toString()` methode

ps: it's maybe easier to read if you use `str.append("\n")` instead of `str.append("|")`